# My function wont work when introducing a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

The task is the following:

```
even    // [1,2,3,4,5].even() should return [2,4]

Array.prototype.even = function(){
  
}
```

I tried to puth an 'arr' parameter in the function and use arr.filter() to solve this. It wont work. New to this prototype thing. I understand a little bit of the background of prototype but how am I supposed to solve this without a parameter?

Comment: Hint: Add `console.log(this)` inside the function.

Comment: _"It wont work"_: well, there's no code in your function. Perhaps you could add the code that doesn't work to your question...?

Comment: @c0m1t solved it! thank you

Comment: @Andy You did not read the text after the code.

Comment: @Maolean, Andy was right, you didn't include the code. You just wrote how your code looks like, it's not the same

Comment: @Maolean, yes I did. But to be able to debug code we actually need code to debug. What you may have written after the code may not have reflected the code accurately.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is what you are looking for

```js
Array.prototype.even = function() {
  return this.filter(e => e % 2 === 0)
}

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].even())
```

Comment: If you're adding to a prototype it's good practice (or at least it used to be) to safeguard them like so: `if (!('even' in Array.prototype)) {...}` just to make sure you're not writing over an existing method. I feel old.